# Gparted showing complete drive unallocated

Tags: dual-boot, partition, gparted

Current Environment Information:
Dual Boot with Windows 7x64 and Linux Mint 16

I am currently trying to install Elementary OS instead of Linux Mint.
Windows works fine but Mint boots fine but has some problems (Cinnamon Crashes and unable to browse other drives) so cannot use for regular use. So I decided of trying the newly released Elementary OS.

I started the Install reached the step for "Installation Type" and selected "Something Else" as I already has the partitions where I would be installing it. But then it didn't show `/dev/sda` partition structure.

[image]

LiveCD runs from sdb1, so I canceled and ran parted, fdisk, fixparts(readonly).

Image from Easues Partition Magic https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJcbq.jpg taken on Windows 7
Here Is the Output:

```
elementary@elementary:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Error: Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.                
elementary@elementary:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x880afec3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   164812799    82302976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       290840760   488392064    98775652+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       164814847   290840759    63012956+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       164814848   196298297    15741725   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       196298298   290840759    47271231    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition table entries are not in disk order
elementary@elementary:~$ sudo fixparts /dev/sda
FixParts 0.8.8

Loading MBR data from /dev/sda

Warning: 0xEE partition doesn't start on sector 1. This can cause problems
in some OSes.

MBR command (? for help): p

** NOTE: Partition numbers do NOT indicate final primary/logical status,
** unlike in most MBR partitioning tools!

** Extended partitions are not displayed, but will be generated as required.

Disk size is 488397168 sectors (232.9 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x880AFEC3
MBR partitions:

                                                   Can Be   Can Be
Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status   Logical  Primary   Code
   1      *           2048       206847   primary              Y      0x07
   2                206848    164812799   primary              Y      0x07
   3             290840760    488392064   logical     Y        Y      0x07
   5             164814848    196298297   logical     Y        Y      0x83
   6             196298298    290840759   omitted                     0x07

MBR command (? for help): s

MBR command (? for help): p

Disk size is 488397168 sectors (232.9 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x880AFEC3
MBR partitions:

                                                   Can Be   Can Be
Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status   Logical  Primary   Code
   1      *           2048       206847   primary              Y      0x07
   2                206848    164812799   primary              Y      0x07
   3             164814848    196298297   logical     Y        Y      0x83
   4             196298298    290840759   omitted                     0x07
   5             290840760    488392064   logical     Y        Y      0x07

MBR command (? for help): q
This will abandon your changes. Are you sure? (Y/N): y
elementary@elementary:~$
```

I am not getting what the problem is! As I had previously successfully installed different versions of Ubuntu's, Linux Mint's.
If anymore information is required please comment. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please move this to SuperUser if It is not good enough here.

Comment: Other Linux and Ubuntu versions except those who are accepted as ["Official Ubuntu flavours"](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours) are off-topic here on AskUbuntu. You may ask your question on [Unix.SE] for all Linux-derivates or on [SU] for all computer questions in general. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partition table looks OK, *but* it's a bit odd. In particular, most partitioning tools put a data structure known as an [Extended Boot Record (EBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record) in the sector immediately preceding the logical partition it describes. In your case, though, there's no gap between your logical partitions 5 and 6, so your partition 6's EBR must be located somewhere else. This is legal, but it's unusual. My *suspicion* is that libparted (used by `parted`, GParted, and most GUI Linux installers) is confused by this placement, resulting in the empty partition table you're seeing.

You might get a little more information on this by running `parted` on the disk, as in:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda print
```

If I'm right, there may be an error message that describes the problem (most likely using confusing terms). It's conceivable that the message will suggest a fix. If so, you could try that (but see my caveat below).

The easiest way to fix this is likely to be to shrink partition 5 or 6 so open up a short gap between them. (Just one sector should be plenty, but most partitioning tools align on 1MiB boundaries, so you may need a 1MiB gap.) The trouble is that GParted doesn't see partitions, so you can't use it; and the built-in Windows tools will most likely try to convert the disk to a [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) format, which will render Linux unbootable. The EaseUS program you used for your screen shot may well do the job safely, but I can't promise that.

If you resize the partitions as I suggest and GParted still shows the disk as empty, run FixParts on it, as you've already done. This time, though, FixParts should not show any partitions as "omitted." You should then be able to type `w` to save your changes (which would be nothing but re-writing EBRs in a way that `parted` would like).

***The big caveat:*** Because your partition table is a bit unusual, any changes you make are ***risky.*** I'm the author of FixParts, so I know its capabilities; but even with FixParts, I can't promise how it will react to your disk after you make the change I suggest. Worse, a resizing operation is risky at the best of times, and because of your partition table oddities, it's even riskier. I ***strongly*** recommend you back up important data before doing anything more with your disk.

Comment: Thanks, for the useful information. But I nuked my linux partition. and the one along side it. (After backing up data) using Easeus Partition Master. Recreated the J drive. And Now I am installing Elementary OS. Also the partitions are visible during Install. I have already started the Install. Hope it goes well.